# How to solve saving failed with TeXstudio?

Tags: compiling, texstudio

when I try to compile or save my document appears the following message:

"Could not get write permissions on file ...

Perhaps it is read-only or opened in another program?"

[image]

I'm using TexStudio, and I have only the `\tex` file open

There's a way to solve it?

Comment: Well, try to save as another name and maybe in another path, with permissions to users.

Comment: If you strike out all the name, we have no idea if its the source.tex which is open thus cannot be modified by an external routine is it one of the support files or is it most likely unable to rebuild the pdf because you are using an external viewer, please help us help you by giving a clue as to which file is locked

Comment: Looking through the blue I spy an x at the end. So either the code to-compile writes to a tex file (which we cannot tell without the code) or the code is edited (and has to be saved before compile) and some other program also has the tex file open and locked. No way to tell.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I would tend to agree and as the start looks like c:\documentos it should be in the users area (thus potentially not a problem) UNLESS it is the wrong users area or it is a red herring and simply need to go to `Tools` and `Clean Auxiliary files` since it may be "stuck" in a failed compilation of the .tex